# How can I access an external hard disk through the network and hide it locally

Tags: networking, hard-drive, security

Say I have a Desktop PC attached to it through the USB an external Hard drive. How can I access that drive through my network using my laptop without letting that drive to be accessed or make it hidden on my desktop PC?

I am Using Windows 7 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: oops sorry, on Windows 7 Ultimate Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Windows 7 machine available to show a screenshot, but in Disk Management you can hide a drive letter.   You could set up a share and then use Disk Manager to keep the drive from being browsable in the local machine's File Explorer.

Comment: In that case, does the drive will be visible over network? if not, hoe to access it?